# Asynchronous method in WCF Service

Tags: multithreading, wcf, sql-server-ce

I am working on a tablet application where I am using Microsoft sync framework for synchronization between the tablet and the Server. WCF is being used. At the time of synchronization, based on certain conditions I need to create a SDF file on the server and insert data into it. I have created asynchronous method which creates SDF and inserts data into it.

The issue is that after inserting few records, the async method terminates throwing System.Threading.ThreadAbortException. I have not used WCF much and having difficulty understanding the reason for this. What can be the possible reasons for such behavior?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like the async method is aborted when the WCF call terminates. How are you hosting your WCF call - under IIS or something else? How do you start your background thread?

Comment: WCF is not getting terminated, only the method thread terminates. I can figure out that from the server log. WCF is hosted under IIS 6. I call the BeginInvoke method of the delegate instance.